# Grails createCriteria duplicate result

Tags: grails, criteria

My criteria is giving me duplicate result so insted of:

```
def history = TerminHistorie.createCriteria().list([max:20, offset:offset])
```

I did :

```
def history = TerminHistorie.createCriteria().listDistinct([max:20, offset:offset])
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to groovy.lang.Closure
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The listDistinct() method does not work well with the pagination options maxResult and firstResult. If you need distinct results with pagination, we currently recommend that you use HQL. You can find out more information from http://floledermann.blogspot.com/2007/10/solving-hibernate-criterias-distinct.html.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked:

```
resultTransformer org.hibernate.Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY
```

Comment: This really doesn't work when using offset and limit because it trims out the duplicates after the query has run. This means that if you ask for 10 back and there are two duplicate records, you'll get eight results leaving your users wondering why there are only eight and not 10 results. Your last page(s) will also fail to work because the totalCount is accurate, but the result counts are not.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
def history = TerminHistorie.createCriteria().listDistinct {
    maxResults(20)
    firstResult(offset)
}
```